# $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ is not finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, finitely-generated

> $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ is not finitely generated ?

Maybe I misunderstood, what finitely generated means. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_module#Formal_definition) it says, we need finitely many elements and I think $1$ and $1/2$ suffices as generators.

But [here](http://modular.math.washington.edu/129/ant/html/node14.html), at the end of Proposition $5.1.4$, from the fact that $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ is not finitely generated it is concluded that $1/2$ is not integral.

Comment: As a $\mathbb Z$-module, $1$ and $1/2$ fail to generate $1/4$.

Comment: I think you're confusing generators as a module and generators as an algebra. $\mathbf Z[\frac12]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbf Z$-algebra, not as a $\mathbf Z$-module.

Comment: If $1,1/2$ generated $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module, then every element would be expressible as $a\cdot 1 + b\cdot \frac{1}{2}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Recall that $\mathbb{Z}[1/2]$ contains the elements $1/2^n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. As a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, we can not write every power $1/2^n$ as a linear combination of a finite set of these with integer coefficients. However, as stated above, $\{1,1/2\}$ are sufficient in a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

Comment: @Eoin OK, but I always thought: $\mathbb Z[1/2]=\{a+b/2 : a,b\in\mathbb Z\}$

Comment: @primitive I thought you might have. But recall $R[a]$ is the smallest ring which contains both $R$ and $a$. So it must be closed under the operation of multiplication and therefore $a^n\in R[a]$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are confusing finitely generated modules with finitely generated algebras. In a module we only have addition and scalar multiplication by the base ring, which in this case is $\mathbb Z$. $\frac1 4$ is not in the submodule generated by $1$ and $\frac 1 2$ because $\frac 1 4$ is not an integer linear combination of these. To see that the module is not finitely generated, note that any finite set of elements will have a largest denominator, and hence elements with larger denominators will not be in the submodule generated by the finite set of elements.

Comment: So $\mathbb Z[1/2]$ does not consist of the elements of the form $a+b/2;a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and being a finitely generated algebra means that we can also take all products of the generators, which is not allowed for a module, right ?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3):

As a $\Bbb{Z}$-algebra, $\Bbb{Z}[1/2]$ is finitely generated, but it is not a finitely generated $\Bbb{Z}$-module!

In fact, if $A=\left\{ \frac{a_i}{2^i} \right\}_{i=1}^N$ is finite subset of $\Bbb{Z}[1/2]$, the $\Bbb{Z}$-submodule generated by $A$ does not contain powers of $\frac{1}{2}$ bigger than $\frac{1}{2^N}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}]$ is a finitely-generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra, but not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module.